# Dog refuses to move during walks

Tags: dogs

When returning from the dog park, my puppy (6 months old) constantly "goes on strike" and stays in down position on the ground. 
He doesn't react to treats, sticks or pulling the leash
Any suggestions?

Comment: Is he tired? I had to carry my puppy home when he was young.

Comment: I don't think he's tired. I believe that if we would stay at the dog park he would continue playing

Comment: Sounds like he wants to keep playing then.

Answer (score 3):

If the the dog's response to positive stimulus, as you tried, is wrong, you can do one of the following things:

- Abandon him. Not really. If he wants to stay in the park, get out of sight. This makes the dog to focus more on you as leader, even when playing or running.
- Negative Leash. If strength allows it, don't pull the leash. One strong and hard pull is more effective than a continous and soft pulling. You won't harm him.

That behavior comes from two sources. First youth and a whole new world to discover. Second, you are not training the calling in a proper way.

Please be careful. If you don't put the calling in his mind when he is young, you'll have inconstences on your adult dog, leading to probably some problems more.

STOP
COME

Are two commands that the dog should response immediately because, in some situations, you could end up in a dogfight, a car accident or who the hell knows.

Answer (score 0):

He could be sore.  At the dog park he was just too excited to show it.

I know I was walking my dog too much and had to scale it back. See if his muscles are sore by applying pressure.

He could also be protesting not being at the park.